# H2O prediction classification on unknown categories

Tags: h2o

Using the machine learning platform H2O (Python in this instance) how can I determine "confidence" on an unknown categorical prediction?

The issue is that I can get great results for known categories, but I also want to run it against data which has categories the model has not seen before. Outputting unknown or N/A would be perfect for these results. As far as I can tell H2O uses sigmoid on the last layer of its deep learning models, so all of the categories add up to one.

Is there an easy way to determine the confidence? I have thought of the following, but neither of them seem like a great idea:

- Include an "unknown" category and assign it random data
- Create an entirely new model that takes the prediction of the first model and tries to determine if it is correct or not

Thanks